# How to create a mongodb schema for one user only?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm learning node.js and mongodb. What I have done by far is a User schema and a Location schema. The User schema and Location Schema are related together by the field `createdBy` (which is in Location schema).
So example:
User schema

```
_id: ObjectId("12313....")
phone: "+12334..."
fullName: "User"
...
```

Location schema

```
_id: ObjectId("12313....")
location: Object
createdBy: "+12334..."
...
```

The idea is that In Location schema will be stored all the locations of all the users that are using the application, and it will be more than one location for each user. So just to get a location of a specific user, the function might take a long time to search each field on the database.

controller/location.js

```
//getting all the location of a specific user
exports.getLocation = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const createdBy = req.params.createdBy

    const getLocation = await Location.find( {createdBy: createdBy} )

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        msg: "Getting all the locations of the user",
        data: getLocation
    })
})
```

How can I create a structure in which each user has his own Location schema and not all together?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)? Then you can add an array of locations to the schema:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a name'],
  },
  phone: Number,
  locations: [String],
});
```

If a location needs to be an object (or subdocument) you can define it like:

```
locations: [{ name: String, street: String }]
```

See [Mongoose docs on arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where I can define the location: ```locations: [{ name: String, street: String }]```

Comment: where `locations: [String],` is in the first example.